# JQuery Ready function doesn't work after button click

Tags: jquery

I have a JQuery Ready function

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $('#<%= txtBlockAmount.ClientID %>').keyup(function (e) {            
   $(this).val(addCommasOnKeyPress($('#<%= txtBlockAmount.ClientID %>').val()));
  });

});


function addCommasOnKeyPress(nStr) {
    nStr = nStr.replace(/\,/g, '')
    nStr += '';
    var x = nStr.split('.');
    var x1 = x[0];
    var x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
}
```

it works nice on the page load. It has some textbox. It has also Dropdown List. When I want to Load Previous Value by Selected DropDown Change then it doesn't work. Have Anybody known?? Please Reply.

Jewel

Comment: This might be a problem with delegation. Take a look at [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: please, show your HTML code

Comment: What is `TextBox` ? It's not an HTML tag, if it's a class use `$('.TextBox')`, if it's an id use `$('#TextBox')`

Comment: I am new to JQuery. Please tell what have to do...

Comment: Or better yet create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: It all depends on what DropDown  is and does. is it a .net control? if yes then is there any postback event happening?

Comment: Yes Rohit its a .net control. how can I manage?

Comment: _"JQuery Ready function doesn't work after button click"_ - What does "doesn't work" mean? A ready function would normally be executed exactly _once_ when the DOM is first ready, not after other events like clicks...

Comment: Also, $('TextBox') is something wrong, if you have a textbox with id TextBox then it should be $('#TextBox')

Comment: so how can i mange nnnnn? have any idea?

Comment: Rohit, it is working with no doubt in first time. heres my actual code    Textbox=$('#<%= txtBlockAmount.ClientID %>').

Comment: Paste your dropdown, textbox html/aspx code here (only the markup, no need for .cs code) and you will get the solution

Comment: if its working fine for first time then try 
$('TextBox').on('keyup', function (e) {             
instead

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function () {
        $('#<%= txtBlockAmount.ClientID %>').val(addCommasOnKeyPress($('#<%= txtBlockAmount.ClientID %>').val()));        
    });


    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%= txtBlockAmount.ClientID %>').keyup(function (e) {            
            $(this).val(addCommasOnKeyPress($('#<%= txtBlockAmount.ClientID %>').val()));
        });

    });

   
</script>

Comment: DropDown: <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOperator_OptDetails" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"
                                        CssClass="txt_medium" Width="254px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlOperator_OptDetails_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                    </asp:DropDownList>

Comment: textbox:   <asp:TextBox ID="txtBlockAmount" runat="server" Style="text-align: right" CssClass="txt_box"></asp:TextBox>

Comment: @Jewel please edit your question with the code that you put in the comments, that's really hard to read.

Comment: Probably, its loosing the keyup event after postback. The best bet would be to bind it .cs page_load method, something like TextBox.AddAttribute("keyup",functionname); Check exact syntax yourself.

Comment: what will b my function name? i m using keyup function

Comment: $(document).ready(function ()                                                                { $('#<%= txtBlockAmount.ClientID %>').keyup(function (e) { $(this).val(addCommasOnKeyPress($('#<%= txtBlockAmount.ClientID                       %>').val()));                                                                                                       });                                                                                                                          });

Comment: Rohit, what will b my function name??                                                     txtBlockAmount.Attributes.Add("onKeyUp", "??(this)")

Comment: function onkeyupmethod(){ $('#<%=txtBlockAmount.ClientID'%>).val(addCommasOnKeyPress($('#<%= txtBlockAmount.ClientID %>').val() }

Comment: txtBlockAmount.Attributes.Add("onKeyUp", "javascript:onkeyupmethod()");

Comment: Please Rohit, Post your last two comments as answer so that I can mark as answer and Everyone will benefit from it

Comment: Cool. So finally it worked! I've posted as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, its loosing the keyup event after postback. The best bet would be to bind it in .cs page_load method, something like

```
txtBlockAmount.Attributes.Add("onKeyUp", "javascript:onkeyupmethod()");
```

Your js function will look like

```
function onkeyupmethod()
{ 
$('#<%=txtBlockAmount.ClientID'%>).val(addCommasOnKeyPress($('#<%= txtBlockAmount.ClientID %>').val();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
var textb = $('#<%=TextBox.ClientID'%>);
$(document).ready(function () {
            textb.keyup(function (e) {            
                this.val(CustomizeFunction(textb.val()));
            });

        });
```

Comment: You put your jQuery object in a variable and you then use $ sign to wrap it again. You could just do `textb.keyup(function (e) {`

Comment: its worked first time on page load. so if wrong then what was it worked?

Comment: your code does not work. Thanks for appreciation. Just added an attribute in .vb which create the function from script side