# For asp textbox its worked. have to work on gridview template field textbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview, textbox

Please see this link:
[Format Number with commas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229938/jquery-ready-function-doesnt-work-after-button-click)

it works nice on asp textbox.

I have to work on gridview templatefield textbox. first time it works on gridview textbox fine. but after postbak it fails.

Please help...

Comment: Specify _fail_. Why do you need to use a jquery method on postback at all?

Comment: @tim sorry, not on the sit. how can i put comma separated values on gridview textbox?

Comment: You need to show us the markup of your gridview, are you using TemplateFields? What is the datasource, what do you want to show in the textbox? Assuming you have a `string[] strings` which you want to separate with comma: `textBox1.Text=string.Join(",",strings);`.

Comment: ok, i'm using TemplateFields. When I input number on Textbox it would be 100,000 when input 100000. it must be on keyup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here's my Script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 function gridviewDispAddonkeyupmethod() {
         $(".**DispAdd**").val(addCommasOnKeyPress($(".**DispAdd**").val()));
 }

function addCommasOnKeyPress(nStr) {
    nStr = nStr.replace(/\,/g, '')
    nStr += '';
    var x = nStr.split('.');
    var x1 = x[0];
    var x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
}

</script>
```

**Here's my gridview Textbox:**

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtDispAdd" **CssClass="DispAdd"** runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

**Here's my gridview row data bound:**

```
Dim txtDispAdd As TextBox = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("txtDispAdd"), TextBox)
txtDispAdd.Attributes.Add("onKeyUp", "javascript:gridviewDispAddonkeyupmethod()")
```

Alhamdulillah, works excellent. Thanks all guys.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing your code withing the if condition

```
if (IsPostBack) 
{
    // Is a postback, do something
} 
else 
{
    // Is not a postback, do something
}
```